# json-get function in lisp

Tags: json, lisp, common-lisp

In these day i'm working to a json parse in prolog and lisp.
yesterday with your help i finished the prolog project and now i need help again.

the funcion is always json-get but now in lisp.

this is the functin that i wrote:

```
(defun json-get (json_obj fields &optional n)
  (let ((place (assoc fields json_obj :test 'string=)))
    (if (null place)
        n
      (ns (second place) t)))
```

the behavior of the funtion should be the same of the prolog predicate.
for example if the input is:

```
CL-prompt> (defparameter x (json-parse "{\"nome\" : \"Arthur\",\"cognome\" : \"Dent\"}"))
X

CL-prompt> x 
(json-obj ("nome" "Arthur") ("cognome" "Dent"))
```

the output should be:

```
CL-prompt> (json-get x "cognome")
"Dent"
```

insted, if the input is:

```
(json-get (json-parse 
                    "{\"name\" : \"Zaphod\",
                     \"heads\" : [[\"Head1\"], [\"Head2\"]]}")
         "heads" 1 0)
```

the output should be:

```
"Head2"
```

the function that i wrote is totally wrong?

P.S. for this project are forbidden functions like SET, SETQ, SETF e MULTIPLE-VALUE-SETQ and  DO, DO*, DOTIMES, DOLIST e LOOP and DEFPARAMETER, DEFVAR e DEFCOSTANT inside a function

thanks guys

edit 1:

this is the description of this funcion,

```
    a json-get function that accepts a JSON object
(represented in Common Lisp, as produced by the json_parse function) and a series of
"Fields", retrieve the corresponding object. A field represented by N (with N a number
greater than or equal to 0) represents an index of a JSON array.
```

edit 2 :
if i try to run json-get lisp answer me with:

`Error: The variable PLACE is unbound.`

Comment: Why are you trying to use `json_obj` as a function name?

Comment: `(json_obj)` should just be `json_obj`.

Comment: You're calling `json-get` with 4 arguments, but it only takes 3. What is the `results` function?

Comment: `json-parse` doesn't seem to return an association list. An a-list is a list of conses, but the first element of `x` is the symbol `json-obj`.

Comment: The `fields` argument to `json-get` is probably supposed to be a list, where each element is for a level of nesting in the JSON object. You need a recursive helper function that handles each level.

Comment: so the first thing i have to do is remove parenthesis of (json_obj)

Comment: Yes, that's just a basic syntax error.

Comment: ok thanks.
now if you look my old posts there is a json-get predicate in prolog. 
So the this function should be works as this predicate

Comment: And in that predicate, the `fields` argument is a list `[F|Fs]`. In Lisp you don't need the `result` argument -- the value should be returned from the function, not unified with a parameter like in Prolog.

Comment: ok so i change result with N? it's correct?

Comment: I have edited the function, now it's better than before?

Comment: What does the result of `(json-parse "[1, 2, 3]")` look like?

Comment: (json-array 1 2 3)

Comment: yeah you're right json-parse doesn't return an assosiacion list. it's a problem for using assoc?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163002/discussion-between-giuseppe-giubaldo-and-barmar).

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement this recursively. You also need to distinguish JSON arrays (which are implemented as a list of elements prefixed with `json-array`) and JSON objects (which are implemented as an association list.

```
(defun json-get (json_obj fields)
  (if (null fields) ; base case of recursion
      json_obj
    (let* ((cur-key (car fields))
           (current (cond ((and (integerp cur-key) 
                                (eq (car json_obj) 'json-array))
                           (nth (1+ cur-key) json_obj)) ; add 1 to skip over JSON-ARRAY
                          ((and (stringp cur-key) 
                                (eq (car json_obj) 'json-obj))
                           (second (assoc cur-key (cdr json_obj) :test #'string=))) ; Use CDR to skip over JSON-OBJ
                          (t (error "~S is not a JSON object or array or ~s is not appropriate key" json_obj cur-key)))))
      (json-get current (cdr fields)))))
```

`fields` has to be a list of fields, so your second example would be:

```
(json-get (json-parse 
                    "{\"name\" : \"Zaphod\",
                     \"heads\" : [[\"Head1\"], [\"Head2\"]]}")
          '("heads" 1 0))
```

and the first example should be:

```
(json-get x '("cognome"))
```

Comment: so and this work with the format (json-obj ("nome" "arthur") ("cognome" "Dent")), am i right?

Comment: Yes, that's why it does `(cdr json_obj)` when calling `assoc`, so that it skips over the `json-obj` symbol.

Comment: ok ok perfect thank you. I have two questions now
1) :test #'string=, it's necessary? and why isn't #"string=
2) so the nested array of second example it' ok? because the description tell about an index to get value of array (like &optional value)

Comment: When the key is a number, it uses `nth`. It adds 1 so it skips over `json-array`.

Comment: mmm sorry i don't understand this.
in this way cur-key is optional yet?

Comment: `cur-key` is just the first element of the `fields` list.

Comment: with this (and (numberp cur-key) (eq (car json_obj) 'json-array) we say that cur-key and the first element of json_obj are equal then move into array?

Comment: It's not telling if `cur-key` is equal to the first element of `json_obj`. It's checking if the first element of `json_obj` is equal to the symbol `json-obj`, and also if `cur-key` is a number.

Comment: is equal to the symbol json-array, no?

Comment: Yeah, got confused between the two cases.

Comment: what is current?

Comment: It's the variable bound in the second line of the `let*`. It's the part of the object accessed by the first field in `fields`.

Comment: can you write an example please?

Comment: So in the first call it's the array in trhe `heads` property of the object, in the second call it's index `1` in that array, and in the third call it's index `0` in that array.

Comment: Your parentheses aren't balanced. Post the actual code. I suspect you have an extra `)` after `let`, so that `if` isn't inside it.

Comment: but your code it's ok the parentheses are balanced, sorry but i don't understand this last comment

Comment: sorry i see that (json-get x '("cognome")). why there is a single quote befor ("cognome)?

Comment: If you don't quote it, it will try to use `"cognome"` as a function name. This is basic Lisp syntax, a list is a function call unless you quote it.

Comment: My comment about parentheses tried to explain the error you got `The variable PLACE is unbound`. There's no such variable in my code.

Comment: thank you, :test #'string=, it's necessary? and why isn't #"string=?

Comment: I don't understand the question. It's the same reason you use `:test` in your original code.

Comment: i try to run the code but lisp respond me with Cannot take CAR of "nome"

Comment: Sounds like you wrote `(json-get "nome" ...)` instead of `(json-get '("nome") ...)`. The fields have to be in a list.

Comment: yeah you're right but now i run it correctly (json-get x '("nome"))
and lisp respond me 
Error: The variable CUR-INDEX is unbound.
parenthes problem?

Comment: if i compile buffer lisp tells me cur-index assumed special

Comment: That should be `cur-key`. I changed the variable name and missed one of the places to edit it.

Comment: yeah! :) another error, Error: NIL is not a JSON object or array or "nome" is not appropriate key

Comment: What was your call to `json-get` like?

Comment: (json-get x '("nome"))

Comment: And what's the value of `x`? It's complaining that `x` is `NIL`, it needs to be an object returned from `json-parse`.

Comment: x is (JSON-OBJ ("nome" "Arthur") ("cognome" "Dent"))

Comment: I had the arguments in the wrong order in the recursive call. Also, I just realized that I need to call `second` to get the value of an object property.

Comment: mmm with the Zaphod example lisp respond me with this error but maybe it's my fault, Error: undefinef JSON object (next-element)

Comment: yeah, i imagined that your code seems to work perfectly